# D-Flip-Flop Hold and Setup Timing

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, clock, flipflop, timing-analysis

I am solving some question to prepare for my exam but got stuck on this one and need your help.

Giving the following circuit:

[image: circuit]

Where input x gets updated `10ns` after clock goes down, I'm also given that clock cycle is `50ns` such that half of it the clock is 1 and the rest the clock is 0.

Plus giving the following timing table:

[image: timing table]

I need to calculate `T_cd(XOR)`.

---

**The Final answer is:** We can't determine how the circuit behaves those can't find the requested value.

So from this I understand that `T_Hold` and `T_Setup` requirements aren't met, So I made a quick check:

Is `T_CD(FF1)+T_CD(Logic)>=T_H(FF2)`? (In this case FF1 is also FF2 and Logic is XOR and OR gates) **Answer: True**

Is `T_PD(FF1)+T_PD(Logic)+T_Setup(FF2)<=T_clk`? (In this case FF1 is also FF2 and Logic is XOR and OR gates and T_clk is the time for full clock circle which is `50ns`) **Answer: True**

Conclusion: `T_Hold` and `T_Setup` requirements aren't met thus we can calculate `T_cd(XOR)`.

I think I am missing few things here especially since in my calculation I never used that value of `10ns`...

Comment: When things aren't clear in my head, I draw a timing diagram.

Comment: @Mattman944 I did and that didn't help a lot, actually it proved everything is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Final answer is: We can't determine how the circuit behaves ... So from this I understand that T_Hold and T_Setup requirements aren't
> met

Not necessarily the conclusion you should make. If this circuit's behavior cannot be determined, then it may mean timing violations have happened due to -

- Either hold **or** setup failed.
- Both setup **and** hold failed.

> Where input x gets updated 10ns after clock goes down,

One way you might want to look into this scenario is -

- Imagine there is another flip-flop-A sitting 'before' to launch data to the flip-flop-B in your circuit, which captures that data.
- This data was launched on the rising edge at flip-flop-A, and is supposed to be captured at flip-flop B at the next rising edge.
- The launched data from flip-flop-A then arrives at the input of OR and XOR gates after 10ns (assuming no wire delays, skews), after the clock goes down. It means effectively it passed thru a propagational delay of \$T_{pd}(in) = T_{clk}/2+10=35 \text{ ns}\$, before it reaches the input of OR and XOR gates.

So our "imaginary" circuit for timing analysis now looks like -

[image]

I guess \$T_{pd}\$ and \$T_{cd}\$ refer to [Propagation and Contamination delays](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/contamination-delay#:%7E:text=The%20propagation%20delay%20tpd,starts%20to%20change%20its%20value.) respectively.

### Setup Analysis at flip-flop B

Consider the worst-delay path to B (with all propagation delays). By inspection, it is thru -

**input delay at x \$ \rightarrow\$ XOR \$ \rightarrow\$ OR**

[image]

Math for satisfying Setup:

$$T_{in}+T_{pd}(XOR)+T_{pd}(OR)+T_{setup}(B)\le T_{clk}$$
$$\implies 35+6+7+4\le 50 \text{ ns}$$
$$\implies \bbox[7px,border:1px solid red]{52\le 50 \text{ ns}} \text{ --- violated! }$$

Hence, from setup analysis itself, we can conclude that this circuit has timing violation and hence its behavior is uncertain. However let's do Hold Analysis as well.

### Hold Analysis at flip-flop B

XOR's contamination delay is unknown. Okay, anyway let's consider the best-delay path to B (with all known contamination delays). By inspection, it is thru -

**\$\text{clock-to-Q of B}\$ \$ \rightarrow\$ XOR \$ \rightarrow\$ OR**

[image]

Math for satisfying Hold:

$$T_{cd}(clk\rightarrow Q)+T_{cd}(XOR)+T_{cd}(OR)\ge T_{hold}$$
$$\implies 5+T_{cd}(XOR)+4\ge 10 \text{ ns}$$
$$\implies \bbox[7px,border:1px solid black]{T_{cd}(XOR)\ge 1 \text{ ns}}$$

The above is true if Hold is assumed to be satisfied in the circuit (which is not mentioned in your question, nor we can conclude). If Hold is also assumed to be violated, then \$T_{cd}(XOR)\$ should be:
$$\implies \bbox[7px,border:1px solid black]{T_{cd}(XOR)< 1 \text{ ns}}$$

Comment: what I don't understand is why in Setup Analysis you didn't consider T_pd of FF? that is what I learnt plus where these 35 came from?

Comment: "It means effectively it passed thru a propagational delay of ()=/2" why /2?

Comment: In Hold Analysis why didn't you take Tcd(clk -> Q) for the FF that you just added too?

Comment: In setup, you have to take the worst delay path. There are three setup paths. I took the worst delay path for analysis. In that path, tpd of B doesn't come into picture.

Comment: Tclk/2, because the given delay of 10 ns is measured from falling edge (as per the question). So half cycle delay has to be added to find the total delay from rising edge.

Comment: Hi, I just re-read your answer and think there is something wrong with calculating T_setup. Let me explain: input changed 10ns after clock goes down which means 35ns after clock goes up. Now the only path we have is from the FF to itself. If the clock rises now then XOR gate 6ns to finish its job, then we wait for input x which tells us "I will be ready in another 29ns" so in total we waited 35 ns. then or needs another 7 ns which makes a total of 42ns lastly we add tpd(FF) + t_setup(FF) and get a total of 66 ns while you got 52

Comment: Your calculations are wrong. You are incorporating tpd of flipflop + xor in your calculations, which is irrelevant timing path for setup as it's a faster path than the 35 ns input path. By the 35ns window, that data already reached or gate within 27 ns. Its not a critical path.

Comment: can you confirm if t_hold for the other path is 44ns?